# Can't run elasticsearch (windows)8.3.3Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [1] output:

Tags: java, elasticsearch

After running bin\elasticsearch.bat

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: starting java failed with [1]
output:

error:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.JvmOption.flagsFinal(JvmOption.java:113)
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.JvmOption.findFinalOptions(JvmOption.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.MachineDependentHeap.determineHeapSettings(MachineDependentHeap.java:59)
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:132)
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.JvmOptionsParser.determineJvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerProcess.createProcess(ServerProcess.java:211)
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerProcess.start(ServerProcess.java:106)
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerProcess.start(ServerProcess.java:89)
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerCli.startServer(ServerCli.java:213)
        at org.elasticsearch.server.cli.ServerCli.execute(ServerCli.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:85)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.launcher.CliToolLauncher.main(CliToolLauncher.java:64)
```

Comment: Your jdk version must be to old. What are tour es version and your jdk version?

Comment: @LeBigCat elasticsearch 8.3 run its own bundled jkd. Anyway, I checked the version for es 8.3.3 and it's 18.0.2. i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to run Elasticsearch 8.3.3 after stopping ES 6.2.1.

I was able to run version 8.3 by deleting 2 environment variables which pointed to the old ES folder (6.2) :

- ES_HOME
- ES_PATH_CONF

Probably updating them to the new Elasticsearch home would work as well.